# Laravel Setup Issue even after setting up Virtual Host and its all dependencies

Tags: laravel-5

I have installed Laravel Project with all its dependencies. Also, Setup Virtual Hosts for the same. But, When I hit the url like say "dev.laravelProject.com" it immediately opening Xampp Dashboard.

I don't know why is that happened.

Any Help Appreciated

Comment: check your v-hosts. Probably you are missing something in there, put your code here and I will tell you. don't forget to restart apache after that

Comment: Virtual Host Code:--

<VirtualHost *:80>   
  ServerAdmin dev.librarymodule.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/LibraryProject/public
     ServerName dev.librarymodule.com

     <Directory /var/www/html/LibraryProject/public>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

Comment: @EzequielFernandez Please have a look on above commented Code.

Comment: It Looks fine. have you add the url to your hosts file and reload apache?

Comment: @EzequielFernandez Yes.
like this:--
127.0.0.1    dev.librarymodule.com

Comment: is this path going to your project? /var/www/html/LibraryProject/public | have you reload apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change your /etc/hosts file to have a mapping of your desired website name(s) (www.example.com), and target IP address (127.0.0.1). I used my local IP address.

```
 IPAddress               Hostname                   Alias
-----------     --------------------------    ------------------
127.0.0.1       www.librarymodule.com         librarymodule.com 
127.0.0.1       www.dev.librarymodule.com     dev.librarymodule.com
```

So, you can set only one domain

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/LibraryProject/public"
    ServerName librarymodule.com
    ServerAlias *.librarymodule.com
    <Directory "/var/www/html/LibraryProject/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

or add first the main one and then the subdomain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/LibraryProject/public"
    ServerName www.librarymodule.com
    ServerAlias librarymodule.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.dev.librarymodule.com
    ServerAlias dev.librarymodule.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/LibraryProject/public"
</VirtualHost>
```

As a final step, you may need to add the websites to Apache by issuing the below commands:

```
# a2ensite librarymodule.com
# a2ensite dev.librarymodule.com


- Reload apache.
```